# Lightbox youtube videos

Tags: jquery, youtube, lightbox, lightbox2

I would like to display YouTube videos with lightbox2, but I don't know how do. On my website, I have already used this lightbox to display photo, mais when I write this :

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5ln4uR4TwQ?rel=0" data-lightbox="lightbox">
    <button class="view-more">
        <img src="images/loupe.png" width="400" alt="loupe">
    </button>
</a>
```

A little white box appears, loading every time.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you can't have a `button` inside an `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
<a href="http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=1811233136844420765" rel="lightvideo">Google video example - default size</a>
```

just change href.
else dont put `button` in `<a></a>`

Comment: I tried :  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dUAXND_ukc" rel="lightvideo" data-lightbox="video1">Video</a> But I have the same result :/

Comment: try this then <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

Answer (score 0):

you could try this to if you know how to get a YouTube embed link:

```
    <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Comment: If I try this, it will create a youtube box, not a lightbox, then a youtube video :/